# One To Many Relationship Using Vector Type

Tags: java, vector, relationship, one-to-many

I am new to Java programming. I just encountered the new concept of using vector type building a one-to-many relationship.
Can you please give me an easy example of using vector type building a one-to-many relationship (including the class, implementation and an example using the class)?

Really much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `java.util.Ovservable` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for relation between one key to many objects.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    private static String[] val1 = {
            "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"
    };

    private static String[] val2 = {
            "u", "i", "o", "p", "[", "]"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        map.put("foo", Arrays.asList(val1));
        map.put("bar", Arrays.asList(val2));

        System.out.println(map.get("foo"));
        System.out.println(map.get("bar"));
    }
}
```

This will result in a console that looks like this :

[image: console]

Edit - if you are forced to use Vectors :

Because Vectors are just lists, the only way to do a one to many relationship with Vectors would be to create a 2 parallel vectors :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    private static String[] val1 = {
            "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"
    };

    private static String[] val2 = {
            "u", "i", "o", "p", "[", "]"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<String> keyVector = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<Vector<String>> valueVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

        keyVector.add("foo");
        keyVector.add("bar");

        valueVector.add(new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(val1)));
        valueVector.add(new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(val2)));

        //now let's say you want to find the objects that correspond with the key "bar"
         String key = "bar";

        for (int i = 0; i < keyVector.size(); i++) {
            if (keyVector.get(i).equals(key)) {
                System.out.println(valueVector.get(i));
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Output :

[image: output2]

Comment: Thanks for the great example. However, I am confused by using the vector type building a one-to-many relationship. Can you also help me with that?

Comment: Well the java [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) class is very similar to an ArrayList, in that it is just a list of objects. If you want relations between objects, the best data structure would be a map; however, if you are forced to use the Vector class for some reason (threadsafe?), I can provide an example of that as well.

Comment: I am in a situation that I have to use Vector class. Can you please give me an example of that?

Really appreciate it.